# YouTube seekTo going back too far in older WebView browsers – is it a bug that’s been fixed or should I code around it?

Tags: android, google-chrome, youtube-api, android-webview, youtube-javascript-api

I have a web page with an embedded inline YouTube video that I control using the API for iframe embeds. The web page shows a video along with associated text and allows the user to click on a text selection to hear/watch that portion of the video as many times as they want (good for learning a foreign language). I use the player.seekTo(seconds, allowSeekAhead) function to move forward and backward in the video.

The seekTo function works fine on my desktop (in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE) as well as on my own Android phone (Samsung A5) in both the stock WebView browser as well as Chrome (video starts playing from the requested point), but when I tried it on some older Android phones (LG & Samsung), the video would start playing further back than the requested time (more than 1 second)

To understand what was happening, I set up a test page where I watched the video’s time (polled the player.getCurrentTime() function every 50ms), and when it reaches 10 seconds, I programmatically seekTo 5 seconds. On my phone as well as the desktop browsers the time goes to 5 seconds and then starts incrementing from there. On the older phones, the time will first go to 5 seconds, but then after half-a-second, jump back to 3.125 or so (there is a slight variation each time), and then the video starts playing from that point.

I checked the userAgent string for the different phones I was using and found that my phone was running Chrome/34.0, while the WebKit browser on the older phones were running Chrome/30.0. When I tried running the test using a Chrome browser on an older phone (Chrome/34), the timing worked correctly.

**My question:** Was the seekTo issue I’m seeing in older Android browsers a bug that was fixed (in which case I just tell people who want to use my site to use Chrome) or is seekTo working correctly in Chrome/34 a “bug” and when a new version of Chrome comes out, it will revert back to the old action (in which case, I should create some sort of kludgy work around)?

**jsFiddle** – I put my test page on [jsFiddle test page](http://jsfiddle.net/7wv0b235/), but while it will work on my desktop, it doesn’t run on my phone (jsfiddle.net/draft/) – not sure why it won’t run on a phone, but at least it will show the code I was using to test the timing. **Update** - the jsfiddle now runs on a phone for testing - I had the code starting the video, which is not allowed on mobile platforms - the user has to initiate the video.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'),
    first_time = true;

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '315',
        width: '560',
        videoId: 'sA0-QXbLnaE',
        playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 0,
        'controls': 0,
        'showinfo': 0,
        'hl': 'en_US',
        'playsinline': 1,
        'rel': 0,
        'modestbranding': 0
        },
        events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function monitorVideoTiming() {
    var player_time = player.getCurrentTime(),
        tmp_string;

    if ((player_time > 10) && (first_time === true)) {
        first_time = false;
        // player.pauseVideo();
        player.seekTo(5, true);
        // player.playVideo();
    }

    if ((!first_time) && (player_time < 11)) {
        tmp_string = $("#time_report").html();
        tmp_string = tmp_string + player_time.toFixed(3) + "<br />";
        $("#time_report").html(tmp_string);
    }
};

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === 1) {
        setInterval(monitorVideoTiming, 50);
    }
}
```

**Note on key frames** – I doubt this is a frame issue, as seekTo goes to the right point on Chrome/34, but backs up on Chrome/30 (the only two versions I have access to for testing), so the variation seems to be in the Chrome version.

Comment: Can you post the part of your code where you are setting the WebView?

Comment: @androider - When I refer to "WebView", I'm referring to the browser that comes standard with Android - on the phones that I've seen, the icon is Planet Earth with "Internet" below it (I'm not creating my own app - just making a regular website (HTML & JavaScript)) - If you have an Android phone that still has the 30.0 version browser installed, you can see the code "failing" using the jsFiddle I linked to above.